Leader Election Kubernetes Leases
Bello is the current implementation of my leader election Java code,

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String podName = System.getenv("POD_NAME");
        logger.info("IM started {}", podName);
        KubernetesClient client = new KubernetesClientBuilder().build();
        LeaderElector leader = client.leaderElector()
                .withConfig(
                        new LeaderElectionConfigBuilder()
                                .withReleaseOnCancel()
                                .withName("Leader Elector")
                                .withLeaseDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(LEASE_DURATION_SECONDS))
                                .withLock(new LeaseLock(
                                        NAMESPACE,
                                        LEASE_NAME,
                                        podName
                                ))
                                .withRetryPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(2L))
                                .withRenewDeadline(Duration.ofSeconds(10L))
                                .withLeaderCallbacks(
                                        new LeaderCallbacks(
                                                () -> LeaderElectionSimulation.run(client),
                                                LeaderElectionSimulation::stopLeading,
                                                LeaderElectionSimulation::runPrimary
                                        )
                                )
                                .build()
                ).build();
        leader.start();

My problem is how to renew the lease lock after acquiring the lease.

Which API client are you using exactly?  In https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java, a LeaderElector doesn't seem to have a .start() method, but .run() is documented to automatically go into a renewal loop if it becomes the leader.
